# How can I disable a form field and set its value to nil with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a `country select field` and a `state select field` in a form.
If the user selects a country option that is not "US", then the state field is disabled.

If the country is not "US", how can I set the state field's value to nil **AND** disable the state select field?

The code below only disables the fields and leaves the value the same after the form is submitted.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
    $("#user_country_code").change(function () {
      if($("#user_country_code option:selected").val() != "US"){
        $("#user_state").val('blank');
        $('#user_state').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else if ($("#user_country_code option:selected").val() == "US"){
        $('#user_state').removeAttr('disabled');
      } else if ($("#user_country_code option:selected").val() == "") { 
        $("#user_state").val('blank');
      } else {
        $('#user_state').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#user_zipcode').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here are the form fields:

```
<select name="user[country_code]" id="user_country_code">
  <option value="US">United States</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" value="---------------">---------------</option>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
</select>

<select name="user[state]" id="user_state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$('#user_state').addAttr('disabled')` instead of `$('#user_state').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: Either way .. according to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dqt310gv/ Your code works as expected .. When I Select Alaska and then select Afghanistan, it returns `null`

Comment: Yea, the issue is that when the form is submitted, it doesn't update the value to nil.